# @Ajax.ActionLink in ASP.NET 5 MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET 5 RC1.

What is the equivalent in `ASP.NET 5` `MVC 6` of `@Ajax.ActionLink`

Example:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show", 
             "Show", 
             null, 
             new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", 
             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
             UpdateTargetId = "dialog_window_id", 
             OnComplete = "your_js_function();" })
```

as used in `ASP.NET 4` `MVC 5`.

I get:

> The name 'Ajax' does not exist in the current context.

in `ASP.NET 5`

Update:

I understand it is not going to be implemented. Is it possible someone can provide me with the taghelper code example alternative?

Comment: I might be wrong, but dont think this is implemented in mvc 6. You would need to creat your own a tag and implement the ajax call yourself.

Comment: It is pretty easy to implement. Basically include the unobtrusive ajax scripts in the page and make a taghelper that can decorate the link with the needed data-ajax* attributes that will be used by the scripts, or just add the data-ajax* attributes directly in your markup without a custom taghelper

Comment: I basically just want to load a partial page inside a div id tag. Something I use to do using the ActionLink in combination with the AjaxOptions. I guess I could use pure jquery ajax which I add to the onclick event. as an alternative as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular html helper with data_ajax parameters, something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link title", "Action", "Controller", null, new
{
   data_ajax = "true",
   data_ajax_method = "GET",
   data_ajax_mode = "replace",
   data_ajax_update = "#update-container"
})
```

Comment: Aren't those underscores supposed to be hyphens?  i.e. "data_ajax" should be "data-ajax"?

Answer (score 5):

#### Explanation

I would go a limb here and say that it's not a helper at that point.

It's a component. It is not simply HTML but also JavaScript. Once you have JavaScript tied to a component, which framework are you using? Are you using pure JavaScript?

If this component is tied to pure JavaScript (no jQuery), it will need to be updated/tested for all current, previous and future versions of every browsers.

And that, is why I'm thinking that it was left to be built as a component rather than built into the framework itself.

Too many moving pieces, too many dependencies on frameworks/software that the client can and will change.

#### Solution

As for a solution, my recommendation is to go with jQuery or something along those lines.

**HTML**

```
<a class="ajaxLink" href="#" data-href="/Project" data-method="DELETE">Delete Project</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.ajaxLink").on('click', function (){
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('data-method'),
            url: $(this).attr('data-href')
        }).then(function() {
            // success callback
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, this can become quite easily a simple client-side solution rather than a server side solution.

I hope this answers your question and solves your problem.

Comment: As always, if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as "Answered" so that the next user can easily find it.

Answer (score 4):

```html
 @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id = Model[i].RoleID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ze-partial-render", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-sm approved", })



<a asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Account" asp-route-area="Global" asp-route-id="@item.RoleID " data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#ze-partial-render"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-sm"></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

**MVC 5 razor syntax**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id = Model[i].RoleID }, 
   new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "partial-render", 
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" },
     new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-sm approved", })

<a asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Account" asp-route-area="Global"
   asp-route-id="@item.RoleID "
   data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET"
   data-ajax-mode="replace"
   data-ajax-update="#partial-render"
   class="glyphicon 
   glyphicon-pencil btn-sm"></a>
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2015) for the `AjaxHelper` not being implemented in ASP.NET 5.

From the ASP.NET team's comments they seem to want to include it in a release it but they're not getting around to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the other answers here very helpful, so I borrowed from them and made a little bit of helper code to ease the transition while I migrate away from Unobtrusive AJAX, eventually, on this project.

While I could make a method like Html.AjaxActionLink, I looked at the silly number of overloads that method has and said that would be a maintainability mess for a small project.  So instead I made a little DTO called AjaxOptions, which I can pass into the Html.ActionLink method.  First, here's the DTO...

```
public sealed class AjaxOptions
{
    public HttpMethod HttpMethod { get; set; } = HttpMethod.Get;
    //public InsertionMode InsertionMode { get; set; } // I left this out because my code only ever uses Replace
    public string UpdateTargetId { get; set; }
    public string OnBegin { get; set; }
    public string OnSuccess { get; set; }
    public string OnComplete { get; set; }

    public object ToAttrs(object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var dictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        dictionary["data-ajax"] = "true";
        dictionary["data-ajax-method"] = HttpMethod.ToString().ToUpper();
        if (UpdateTargetId != null)
        {
            dictionary["data-ajax-mode"] = "replace";
            dictionary["data-ajax-update "] = '#' + UpdateTargetId;
        }
        if (OnBegin != null)
            dictionary["data-ajax-begin"] = OnBegin;
        if (OnSuccess != null)
            dictionary["data-ajax-success"] = OnSuccess;
        if (OnComplete != null)
            dictionary["data-ajax-complete"] = OnComplete;
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Which allows me to make nice calls into Html.ActionLink like so...

```
@(Html.ActionLink("Add Endorsement", "_CreateEndorsement", new { certificateId = Model.Id },
  new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "modal-content", OnSuccess = "OnEditModalOpened" }
    .ToAttrs(new { id = "create-endorsmeent-link" })))
```

Having to call .ToAttrs might seem a little hokey, but I looked at doing fancy stuff with dynamic and anonymous objects, and I quickly concluded this was the cleaner solution, especially given that I hope to throw all this away within the next few months in favor of "proper" AJAX calls.

*Note: when re-using this code, please note the hard-coded options and adapt them as-needed for your code.  I did not cover all possible options (properties) that exist in the original AjaxOptions class!*

Answer (score 0):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Verify", "VeriFyPackage", "Admin", new { RequestID = item.RequestID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "getpackage" }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```